# Exclude all paths except specific apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I need to make app responsible only for specific paths and all other paths are excluded. I'm trying to make `apple-app-site-association` config the next way, but no luck

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAMID.app_bundle",
                "paths": ["NOT /", "/questions/*", "/goods/*", "*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

what do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is exactly what I looked for:

First options in `path` should be paths, that allowed to your app.

The final option should be `"NOT *"` if you want to exclude all paths, except allowed.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAMID.app_bundle",
                "paths": ["/questions/*", "/goods/*", "NOT *"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```